PrimeNG menu not opening when button is clicked
I have a button on my website which is meant to open a PrimeNG popup menu when clicked. I plan to change the design of only that button later. However, nothing happens when I click it.
The menu shows up without the button.
Why is this?
app.component.html
<div class = "background">
    <div id = pLogo>
      <img src = "../assets/logo-dark.svg" width="30%" height="30%" alt="P">
    </div>
    <div id = BurgerMenu>
      <p-menu #menu [model]="items" [popup]="true" />
      <p-button (onClick)="menu.toggle($event)" icon="pi pi-ellipsis-v"/>
    </div>
</div>

app.component.ts
:host ::ng-deep .p-button { 
    background-color: #00a19c;
    border-color: #00a19c;
    font-family: "Museo Sans 900", Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

:host ::ng-deep .p-button:hover { 
    background-color: #00928d;
    border-color: #00928d;
    font-family: "Museo Sans 900", Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { DividerModule } from 'primeng/divider';
import { RippleModule } from 'primeng/ripple';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MenuModule } from 'primeng/menu';
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
import { MenuItem, MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, ButtonModule, DividerModule, RippleModule, CommonModule, MenuModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'login_app';
  LoadingStatus = true
  items!: MenuItem[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.LoadingStatus = false;  // Remove the loading screen after the animation
      }, 2000);
    this.items = [
            {
                label: 'Options',
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'Refresh',
                        icon: 'pi pi-refresh'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Export',
                        icon: 'pi pi-upload'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];  
    }
  }

Thank you!
Edit:
Adding provideAnimations() in app.config helped fix this for me, though older versions might need BrowserAnimationsModule in app.component.ts.

issue not reproducible on stackblitz please replicate the issue on stackblitz and share back on the question!

@NarenMurali solved, thank you!
